# Delete GridviewRow using Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I've a gridview in which there is an add and remove row facility.I want to knoow how could i remove a particular gridview row when corresponding remove button is clicked.

I've searched everywhere but nothing find quite useful to me

Heres my code

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="gdlbtnRemove" runat="server" 
     OnClientClick="RemoveRow(this)">Remove</asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function RemoveRow(rowindex,objref)
  { 
    var row=objref.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.Remove();  
  }
 </script>
```

Im new to javascript........

Comment: as you say you are new to javascript,I would recommend you use Kendo Grid very helpful and open source 

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/overview/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

apsx:

```
<ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:LinkButton  ID="gdlbtnRemove" runat="server"     
     OnClientClick="return RemoveRow(this)">Remove</asp:LinkButton> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

Javascript:

```
function RemoveRow(item) {
    var table = document.getElementById('myGridView');
    table.deleteRow(item.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Here the problem is after clicking the remove button corresponding gridview row is disappearing first and then reappearing

Comment: This could happen if the click event bubbles up and the page posts back. The `return RemoveRow(this)` in the LinkButton definition combined with returning false on the handler function should stop the bubbling of the this event.

Answer (score 1):

Old post i know but Tsachi's Answer was almost perfect for me except

This

```
var table = document.getElementById('GridviewID');
```

had to become this

```
var table = document.getElementById("<%= GridviewID.ClientID %>");
```

In case anyone else looks at this